# Change X and Y axis font color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I change the color of the X and Y axes labels?
I was trying to use `fontColor` within `scaleLabel` but I might be doing it in the wrong place ?

I tried applying it within `scale` as [can be found on the source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.scale.js#L28). I also tried under `scales` and even within `xAxes`.

```
var options = {
type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scale: {
            scaleLabel:{
                fontColor: 'red'
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
 };
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/owy49hqh/4/)

[image]

I've been checking [the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-radial-linear-scale) but it doesn't seem to be very clear to me. 
And as chart.js doesn't provide enough examples, it is not easy to find out things sometimes...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
//Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor='red';
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
       legend:{labels: {fontColor: 'orange'}},
      title: {
            display: true,
            fontColor: 'blue',
            text: 'Custom Chart Title'
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    fontColor: 'red'
                },
            }],
          xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: 'green'
                },
            }]
        } 
        
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You can use **fontColor** inside **ticks/label/legend:labels** for a particular axis,

```
options: {
        legend: {
             labels: {
                  fontColor: 'orange'
                 }
              },
        title: {
            display: true,
            fontColor: 'blue',
            text: 'Custom Chart Title'
        }     ,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    fontColor: 'red'
                },
            }],
          xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: 'green'
                },
            }]
        } 

    }
```

or change the **defaultFontColor** to change font color of entire text elements drawn on the canvas.

```
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor='red';
```

Comment: I have updated my code, the code which I previously wrote was for chart.js 1.x. I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.scale.js) and found that it has to be changed inside `ticks`.

Comment: And couldn't you find that in the docs? It seems quite weird to me we are forced to check the sour-code to such a simple task.

Comment: Yes, the doc is not clear enough, takes sometime to understand. I have added a snippet above to change font-color of title, legend, scale and label in a chart.

Answer (score 4):

I might be late to this question, but this answer may be useful for people who are looking for the answers.

**In Chart.js, to style the scale label and ticks we can use the below settings.**

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: { // To format the scale label
                display: true,
                labelString: 'X axis name',
                fontColor: '#000000',
                fontSize: 10
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: "black", // To format the ticks, coming on the axis/labels which we are passing
                fontSize: 14
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Y axis name',
                fontColor: '#000000',
                fontSize: 10
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: "black",
                fontSize: 14
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=labels) for all the properties. Study all the properties before doing your implementation.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

React JS - Create React App

```
"chart.js": "^3.7.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
```

I struggled with this problem, unfortunately accepted answer did not work for me, but then I tweaked it little bit and made it work.

Here is what I ended up with, hope this will be helpful for someone...

[image]

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
                color: "#ffffff",
            }
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'License Usage',
            color: "#ffffff"
        },
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: {
            ticks: {
                color: "#ffffff"
            },
        },
        xAxes: {
            ticks: {
                color: "#ffffff"
            },
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if we set the options as below then the font color of axes label values changes. For example I tried it on jsfiddle and it worked.  The same also worked for my chart in rails app.
...

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
                fontColor:'red'
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

To change your chart object ticks and axes labels, do like so:

```
let changeItemColor = (item) => {
    item.scaleLabel.fontColor = color;
    item.ticks.fontColor = color;
    item.ticks.minor.fontColor = color;
    item.ticks.major.fontColor = color;
};
chart.options.scales.xAxes.forEach((item) => changeItemColor(item));
chart.options.scales.yAxes.forEach((item) => changeItemColor(item));
chart.update();
```